# How to set alphaValue in swift ?

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6, nsview

I have a subclass of NSView and i have no idea  what function i should call to change alpha value . In objective c is easy :

```
 [self setAlphaValue: 0.5];
```

but in swift i couldn't find the right function.

```
override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect){
        backgroundColor.set()
    //  self alphaValue(0.56)


        let bezierPath = NSBezierPath(roundedRect:self.bounds, xRadius:self.frame.size.width/2, yRadius:self.frame.size.width/2)
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 2.0
        bezierPath.fill()
    }
```

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Objective-C code

```
[self setAlphaValue: 0.5];
```

can be written using the property notation as

```
self.alphaValue = 0.5;
```

which directly translates to Swift as

```
self.alphaValue = 0.5
```